# .NET MAUI BlazorWebView - how to load a URL at startup

Tags: maui-blazor, .net-maui

I am new to the .NET 6.0 and specifically MAUI.

I have created a multi-platform Blazor standard template project using Visual Studio Preview (17.2).

The standard template project loads index.html inside the project.

I would like to be able to load an external url on startup instead.

I would appreciate any pointers on how to do this correctly.

Thanking you in advance.